# How do variables between functions and void functions work / interact with each other?

Tags: c++

Watching this https://youtu.be/_bYFu9mBnr4 tutorial.From what I understand functions and void functions can be called and they would perform the code within them.

However I don't understand the purpose of the variables within the parenthesis. The code won't work if even one of them is missing. However it seems like you can assign theses variables different names and it could still work.

How do these variables connect / interact with each other? Referring to:

1.) double power ***(double base, int exponent)***

2.) void print_pow ***(double base, int exponent)***

3.) print_pow ***(base, exponent);***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double power(double base, int exponent)
{ 
    double result = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
}

void print_pow(double base, int exponent)
{
    double myPower = power (base, exponent);
    cout << base << " raised to the " << exponent << " power is " << myPower << ". \n ";
}

int main()
{ 
    double base;
    int exponent;
    cout << "What is the base?: ";
    cin >> base;
    cout << "What is the exponent?: ";
    cin >> exponent;
    print_pow(base, exponent);
}
```

Comment: I suggest learning C++ from a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of a youtbube series.

Comment: The name of the variables in the function has nothing to do with the variable names in your "main function". I did not saw the tutorial but if it does not explain how variables work and how to pass them, I am not sure if the tutorial itself is good. So to quickly summarize it, the "base and exponent" in main() has nothing to do with "base and exponent" in print_pow() and in power() they are only named the same because you choosed it so. You could name them whatever (almost) you want. The only connection they have, is that you pass the one variable to the other on, when you call the function

Answer (score 4):

Imagine this code, by itself, alone:

```
double power ()
{ 
    double result = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Can you tell me what is `base` and `exponent` and where they came from?

The answer is no. If you can't say, neither can the compiler. In my code, `base` and `exponent` has not been declared.

These are called *function parameters*. They are exactly what they sound like. A good analogy could be made with the mathematical notation:

```
f(x) = x * 2
```

In the parenthesis lies the parameters of the function.

---

Now consider a code very similar to your, but with the name of the parameter changed:

```
double power(double base, int exponent)
{ 
    double result = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
}

// Name changed!  ----v------v
void print_pow(double b, int e)
{
    double myPower = power(b, e);
    cout << base << " raised to the " << exponent << " power is " << myPower << ". \n ";
}
```

As you can see, parameters can be mapped to each other independently of their names. `base` will take the value of `b` and `exponent` will take the value of `e`.

An important property of function parameter is that they act just like local variable. Such local entity is not influenced by the name of an external entity. So if inside your code they are multiple variables named `base` and `exponent`, they are distinct entity since they have different *scopes*.

If you'd like, you could write such function:

```
void print_pow2(double base, int exponent)
{
    double myPower = power(base * 2, 3);
    cout << base << " raised to the " << exponent << " power is " << myPower << ". \n ";
}
```

As you can see, even though the name is the same, `base` and `exponent` won't have the same value inside `power`. You can even notice that the `exponent` inside `power` will have no relation to the `exponent` in `print_power2` as I sent the constant `3`.

If I do an analogy to the mathematical notation again:

```
f(x) = x * 2
g(x) = f(x * 2) / 3
```

Even though `g` and `f` have both `x` as parameter, that `x` is different and take up a different value in each functions.

Answer (score 2):

The naming scheme applied here is a bit unfortunate. The names of those variables could be almost anything, and it is advisable to spend some time to find good names. Though, to merely illustrate that they are different entities, I just made them different:

```
 #include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

double power (double base, int exponent)
{ 
    double result = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
}

void print_pow(double a, int b)
{
    double myPower = power (a, b);
    cout << a << " raised to the " << b << " power is " << myPower << ". \n ";
}

int main()
    { 
        double x;
        int y;
        cout << "What is the base?: ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "What is the exponent?: ";
        cin >> y;
        print_pow(x, y);
    }
```

Variables are declared in a certain scope. Only within this scope you can access the variable. In your code there are `3` different variables called `base`. There is no magic relation between then, just because they share the same name. They are "connected" by calling the function with parameters `print_pow(x,y)`, the name of parameters is not relevant for the function and the name of the functions arguments are not that relevant for the caller (other than giving a hint on what the argument is used for).

Answer (score 0):

> How do these variables connect / interact with each other?

There is **no relation** between the names of your function parameters and the names of other variables used outside of the function.

*They are different variables, and it doesn't matter whether or not their names match*.

When you define parameters such as `double base, int exponent`. in...

```
double power (double base, int exponent)
{ 
    double result = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < exponent; i++)
    {
        result = result * base;
    }
    return result;
}
```

... you are telling the compiler that **any** values passed to your function `power` will become new variables `double base` and `int exponent` inside of your function.

When your function completes, those new variables no longer exist.